# Conforming an actor to Sequence protocol

Tags: swift, concurrency, swift-concurrency

How can one conform an actor to the `Sequence` protocol? The following code generates the compiler warning:

> Instance method 'makeIterator()' isolated to global actor 'MainActor' can not satisfy corresponding requirement from protocol 'Sequence'

```swift
@MainActor class Test: Sequence {
    private var contents: [Int] = []
    
    func makeIterator() -> Array<Int>.Iterator {
        contents.makeIterator()
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't believe an Actor can conform to Sequence. Its values cannot be accessed without awaiting, which is required by Sequence. You should be able to conform it to AsyncSequence.

Comment: My actual goal is to conform to `RandomAccessCollection`. I had hoped starting with conformance to `Sequence` this was going to be a good step to help me learn, but I'm realising how much Swift concurrency has turned my understanding upside down.

Comment: Same thing; an Actor can't conform to RandomAccessCollection. That would be particularly problematic, since the `count` and elements could change behind the caller's back. (If the contents are immutable, there's no point to it being an Actor.) Instead the Actor should provide its contents as a property/method. For example, `let elements = await actor.elements`. Then `elements` would be a snapshot of the Actor's contents at some point in time, and it could definitely conform to RandomAccessCollection.

Comment: @RobNapier An actor can still conform to `Sequence` (or any non-async protocol such as `Hashable`) so long as it marks the required methods as `nonisolated`. Of course, you would not be able to access any of the actor-isolated properties, which means an actor might not be ideal for `Sequence`. `AsyncSequence` is a better fit for an actor

Answer (score 6):

Applying a global actor, like `@MainActor`, to a type declaration adds an implicit `@MainActor` in that type's properties and methods.

This means that your example is equivalent to:

```swift
class Test: Sequence {
    @MainActor private var contents: [Int] = []
    
    @MainActor 
    func makeIterator() -> Array<Int>.Iterator {
        contents.makeIterator()
    }
}
```

This is an issue because `Sequence` has a `makeIterator` requirement that is not isolated to a specific global actor. If this was the case you wouldn't be able to use a for-loop on an `Array` in a background thread. So, to opt-out of the implicit isolation, you can write:

```swift
@MainActor class Test: Sequence {
    private var contents: [Int] = []
    
    nonisolated func makeIterator() -> Array<Int>.Iterator {
        // You can't use the isolated property 'contents'
        // here, because it's isolated
    }
}
```

Perhaps you intend to make `Test` conform to a `Sequence`-like protocol whose requirements are isolated to `@MainActor`. Unfortunately, a similar feature has only been [proposed](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0313-actor-isolation-control.md#isolated-protocol-conformances) as a future direction.

If you are still confused, it's worth taking a step back and thinking about what you really want to achieve. Actor isolation offers a way to safely mutate data shared across threads. Thus, no isolation implies either a lack of mutation (hence the ability to mark `let` properties `nonisolated`) or a synchronization mechanism other than actors.